# UCanAccess: Bug when inserting new rows to tables with attachments

Tags: java, ms-access, ucanaccess

After several hours of trying and failing, I've identified what looks like curious behaviour by UCanAccess when trying to insert a new row into a table that coincidentally has a field of type Attachment.

Specifically, I have a simple table in Access as follows:

```
   ID: Autonumber 
   FirstName: String (not required)
   Age: Numnber (not required)
   Picture: Attachment (not required)
```

I use the follow code to add a row to the table using Java and UCanAccess:

```
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");  
String database = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + dbFileName +  "";                           
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
Statement s = conn.createStatement();

String sql = "INSERT INTO Test(FirstName, Age) VALUES ('TestName',32)";
s.execute(sql);
```

The code produces the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.ucanaccess.commands.InsertCommand.persist(InsertCommand.java:153)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.flushIO(UcanaccessConnection.java:315)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.commit(UcanaccessConnection.java:205)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.AbstractExecute.executeBase(AbstractExecute.java:217)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.Execute.execute(Execute.java:46)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.execute(UcanaccessStatement.java:152)
    at projectmigrator.ProjectMigrator.tester2(ProjectMigrator.java:62)
    at projectmigrator.ProjectMigrator.main(ProjectMigrator.java:43)
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.1 null
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.execute(UcanaccessStatement.java:154)
    at projectmigrator.ProjectMigrator.tester2(ProjectMigrator.java:62)
    at projectmigrator.ProjectMigrator.main(ProjectMigrator.java:43)
Caused by: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.1 null
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.commit(UcanaccessConnection.java:212)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.AbstractExecute.executeBase(AbstractExecute.java:217)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.Execute.execute(Execute.java:46)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.execute(UcanaccessStatement.java:152)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.1 null
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.flushIO(UcanaccessConnection.java:348)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.commit(UcanaccessConnection.java:205)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.ucanaccess.commands.InsertCommand.persist(InsertCommand.java:153)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.flushIO(UcanaccessConnection.java:315)
    ... 6 more
```

Interestingly, the code runs without errors if I substitute the sql String to

```
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Test(FirstName, Age, Photo) VALUES ('TestName',3224,'')";
```

Am I really forced to supply a dummy-value like an empty string when executing an INSERT INTO a table that contains an unrequired Attachment-typed field (this is not the case for fields of other types such as Number or Text). Could this be a bug in UCanAcces or am I missing anything?

(Thanks - I know I should be using PreparedStatement for such INSERT INTO statements, but have hard coded the insert for the sake of this post).

Comment: Fixed formatting - hopefully the post is easier to read now:)

Comment: I can reproduce the issue and will escalate.

Comment: Pay attention, this bug will be fixed in the 4.0.2. The workaround found has limited validity and for the above described case, so it's better to use the approach described on the UCanAccess website to set complex column values. The 4.0.2 will come fairly soon.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in UCanAccess 4.0.2.